# UITableView, breaks with 6+ rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am really stuck with this problem, it seems really odd, and I hope someone is able to see the issue!

I have a tableview controller, which I am populating from an array of dictionaries.  Each cell has a label, and a text field.  The user enters a value into the text field, then presses a save button.  At which point, the code loops over the table view, and stores the entered values into a plist file.

Until there are 6 or more rows in the table...

the code that populates the cells

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath       *)indexPath
{
  NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NewParamCell";
 NewParameterSetCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier    forIndexPath:indexPath];

int row = [indexPath row];
NSDictionary *thisParam = [_AllowedParams objectAtIndex:row];

cell.ParameterLabel.text = [thisParam objectForKey:@"parameter"];
cell.ParameterUnit.text = [thisParam objectForKey:@"unit"];

return cell;
}
```

the code that processes the save action is :

NSMutableDictionary *ContainerDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

```
// loop over table cells
for (int section = 0; section < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
        NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

        NewParameterSetCell* cell = (NewParameterSetCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];

            NSMutableDictionary *CurrentParam = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [CurrentParam setObject:cell.ParameterLabel.text forKey:@"parameter"];
            [CurrentParam setObject:cell.ParameterUnit.text forKey:@"unit"];
            [CurrentParam setObject:cell.ParameterReading.text forKey:@"reading"];

            [ContainerDict setObject:CurrentParam forKey:cell.ParameterLabel.text];
    }
}
```

with 1 - 5 table rows this code works perfectly, but as soon as there are 6 or more rows, the code stops being able to map the cell at position 0,

```
NewParameterSetCell* cell = (NewParameterSetCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];
```

This returns nil, but ONLY for the first iteration, ie position 0. if I put a try catch around it, the code carries on, but I only get 5 of the 6 values saved to the plist.

This is driving me absolutely nuts, if anyone has an idea as to what is wrong I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Can you post your numberOfRowsInSection method?

Comment: Why are you iterating over all of the cells? You should be iterating through your data model.

Comment: What you're doing is bad practice. Cells are for displaying data, not for providing it. You shouldn't be getting values out of the cells, but out of your model.

Comment: @rmaddy Hi, I am a bit of a ios novice, so I am not 100% sure what you mean, my cells have text fields in them, and this was the only way I could think of to get the value out?

Comment: @remus Hi the method is - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{// dictionary containing labels etc
    return _AllowedParams.count;
}

Comment: See babibo's answer - you need to implement that delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the tableView recycles the cells, so when the table grows the cell at row 0 does not exist anymore (table view has recycled it already and used it for the 6th item).

Instead of trying to set the properties of all of the cells (which does not exist), try to set them just for the cells that would be displayed. For that you can use a UITableViewDataSource and implement this method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

EDIT:

Depending on the iOS version you want to support here is an example of the method implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[NewParameterSetCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
  }

  // Configure the cell here based on indexPath …

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but would be nice to see an example of the method delegate implemented.

Comment: @babibo Hi, thanks for the reply. //Edit,  Yes, I am using that exact method to set the cells when the controller loads, my problem is coming from reading the values in the text fields that are inside the cells, when the user presses the save button

Comment: If your text field is in a row that would be off screen by the time you press the save button, you would not have access to its content since the cell might not exist anymore.

Comment: What you can do is to use -tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath: to keep track of the content of textFields which are off the screen